# QProcess finished signal parameters lambda function

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside2, qprocess

I'm new to handling `lambda` functions in a qprocess signal-slot environment. I'm having a problem with the parameters of the function. In particular with the finished() signal. According to the documentation, it accepts two parameters: `def finished (exitCode, exitStatus)`

I'm trying somerhing like this:

```
for i, thing in enumerate(something):
    self.proc_codificar.append(Qprocess())
    #(code here)
    self.proc_codificar[i].finished.connect(lambda exitCode, exitStatus, proc=self.proc_codificar[i]: self.codificar_fin(exitCode, exitStatus, proc))
    #(code here)
```

And on process finished I want to know exitCode, exitStatus, and the process itself

```
def self.proc_codificar(self, exitCode, exitStatus, proc)
    print(exitCode)
    print(exitStatus)
    print(proc)
```

But this way is not working. What is the correct way to handle the `lambda` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finished signal of QProcess in PySide2 is overload so there are 2 signatures(see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QProcess.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QProcess.finished)):

- `PySide2.QtCore.QProcess.finished(exitCode, exitStatus)`
- `PySide2.QtCore.QProcess.finished(exitCode)`

**Note:** The second method is marked as deprecated so in the next versions it could be eliminated.

Given the above, you must indicate the signature in the connection:

```py
for i, thing in enumerate(something):
    process = QProcess()
    # (code here)
    process.finished[int, QProcess.ExitStatus].connect(
        lambda exitCode, exitStatus, proc=process: self.codificar_fin(
            exitCode, exitStatus, proc
        )
    )
    # (code here)
    self.proc_codificar.append(process)
```

**Note:** In PyQt5 and Qt/C++ this does not happen.